# Make ajax request upon programmatically switching tabBarController viewContoller

Tags: iphone, ios, tabbarcontroller, selectedindex

I've been reading through forum posts and banging my head for over 2hrs now and hopefully someone can help point me in the right direction.

I am using the UITabBarController and have 4 root views associated to it.
In the first view, the user can take a picture (UIImagePicker), after which the second view is displayed programmatically.  Once the second view is displayed I want to make an ajax request to a server.

I am able to sucessfully select/display the second view with the following code:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

However the UITabBarControllerDelegate method (which is successfully called upon user tabBarContoller *touches*):

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

is not called, as Apple [tabBarController:didSelectViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) states:

> In versions of iOS prior to version 3.0, this method is called only when the selected view controller actually changes. In other words, it is not called when the same view controller is selected. In addition, the method was called for both programmatic and user-initiated changes to the selected view controller.

So my question is: "**How can I execute some code & make a request after programmatically switching to second view?**"

I also tried putting traces in:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear 
-(void)ViewWillAppear 
-(void)viewDidLoad
```

but none of those are called when tabBarController.selectedIndex is set.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewWillAppear` should be called.. I just tested it.

Another solution: use the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` with

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

for tracking changes.

Comment: I implemented `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` in my two views  (HomeViewController and ViewerViewController), and I see that it is indeed being called when I select the HomeViewController, but not when I select ViewerViewController -- would you have any ideas/tips why this would be?  Thanks

Comment: found the problem: i forget to the set the 'Class Identity' for the ViewerViewController in IB... thanks for helping to direct me towards this.

Comment: I dont know your code. But `viewWillAppear:` should be called. Just tested it again with a two ViewControllers. In each of them I fire a `performSelector:withObject:andDelay` to a method which will change the selected index of the TabBarController. And I can see (NSLog) that `viewWillAppear:` gets called every time.

Comment: thanks for your answer regarding viewWillAppear as it enabled me to do what I was trying to do.  I am curious however how your suggestion above "another solution: UITabBarControllerDelegate" is different to what I was doing in my original question?  Thanks